# OpenGL ES: Vertex/Color Buffers/Pointers

Tags: android, colors, buffer, opengl-es-2.0

I have a large volume of points I'm reading from a file that have both 3D positions and RGB values. I'm struggling to render these via Java+Android+OpenGL(ES).

I create a vertex buffer, and color buffer:

```
private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer, colorBuffer;
```

Pin my vertices to the buffer:

```
ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(lasVertices.length * 4);
vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
vertexBuffer.put(lasVertices);
vertexBuffer.position(0);
```

And in my draw (GL10 gl):

```
gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glColorPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, colorBuffer);
gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
gl.glPointSize(3);
gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_POINTS, 0, 100);
gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

Which does draw a small sample of 100 points on the screen, but without color. I've pinned the color into the `colorBuffer` I created above while running code, as such:

```
lasColors[i*3] = array[i].red;
lasColors[i*3+1] = array[i].green;
lasColors[i*3+2] = array[i].blue;
```

But How can I render the unique values in step with the positions of the vertices?

I tried what I did with the positions:

```
vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(lasColors.length * 4);
vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
colorBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
colorBuffer.put(lasColors);
colorBuffer.position(0);
```

and showing this into my draw function:

```
gl.glColorPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, colorBuffer);
```

...but didn't get any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enabling the color array along with the vertex array and see if that works.

```
gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
gl.glColorPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, colorBuffer);
gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
gl.glPointSize(3);
gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_POINTS, 0, 100);
gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

Comment: Hmmm.  You said that the points are appearing though?  Are they all the same color?  And if so, what color?

Comment: I did a little digging, and even if it doesn't solve your entire problem, you must include the glEnableClientState() line according to the [documentation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glColorPointer.xml).  You could also try using RGBA values for the colors instead of just RGB.  Using only 3 values has caused problems for [others](http://www.machwerx.com/2009/01/26/glcolorpointer-size-must-be-4/) in the past.

Comment: Thank you. I do get color (its not what I want, but it is color).